# ASP.NET CORS Exception on POST with a react app

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, cors, webapi

I have a react app calling my service with CORS enabled from my local app. This works fine for GET methods but for some reason it throws a CORS exception when calling a POST method. Is there anything I need to add to configure for POST? thanks

in my startup.cs:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins(
                            "http://localhost:3000"
                            );
                    });
            });
```

In my react app the call is pretty basic:

```
  axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: `https://localhost:44340/patientsearch`,
            data: { searchModel },
          });
```

The exception:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44340/patientsearch' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: I googled your error and found this: https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9

Look at that, that might solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, that doesn't answer the question.... @MartinZ

Comment: Already tried the suggested fixes? @Funky

Comment: yes no joy @MartinZ

Answer (score -1):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {            
            app.UseCors(x =>
            {
                x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithOrigins("https://localhost:5002");
            });           
        }
```